# how to update a primary key that is also a foreign key in another table with petapoco?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, petapoco, micro-orm

```
public class User {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
public class Phone {
   public int Id{get;set}
   public int UserId{get;set;} // foreign key
}
```

How can i update a `User.Id` property with `PetaPoco` ?
`user.Update("set id = @NewId where id = @OldId",new { NewId = new_id,OldId = id});`
Did not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option for foreign keys was the simplest solution !